# How to access single url while youtube-dl extract playlist information

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl, ytdl

So, I made a discord bot and I need to extract the information from a playlist while playing music because my internet is slow. This is the code that I've tried.

```
import sys
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
import threading
import time

info = []

class Logger():
    def debug(self, msg):
        print(f"Debug -> {msg}")
    def error(self, msg):
        print(f"Error -> {msg}")
    def warning(self, msg):
        print(f"Warning -> {msg}")

def buffer():
    global info
    url = "playlist"

    ytdl_opts = {
        "cookiefile": "cookies.txt",
        "logger": Logger(),
    }

    ytdl = YoutubeDL(ytdl_opts)
    info = ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False)

try:
    task = threading.Thread(target=buffer)
    task.daemon = True
    task.start()

    while task.is_alive():
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            length = len(info["entries"])
            print(f"Length -> {length}")
        except TypeError:
            print(f"No entry.")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(f"Interupt.")
```

I want to make the length increasing too while extracting url so I can access several information from there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're best off learning how to use lavalink and letting it do that for you, you can get started here: https://github.com/Devoxin/Lavalink.py and https://github.com/freyacodes/Lavalink/